# Using .net and vb, how can I work with sessions and dynamic variables?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I am looking for some advice. I need a way to keep track of services that users will be adding, editing, and removing. I believe using session variables would be good so that I don't need to fill databases with information until the user has submitted their changes at the end.

There will be service IDs, such as 1, 2, 3, etc. There will be actions, such as A, E, D for add, edit, and delete per each service ID. There will be a form to fill out based on the service ID and action.

I need to track, for example:

- Service ID: 1
- Action: A
- Form: First Name, Last Name, Address, etc

How can I tie these variables together dynamically?

If I create a session for first name, it can just hold one first name. I need this first name to be tied to the ID and Action.

```
Dim FirstName As String = CType(Session.Item("FirstName"), String)
```

So I think I need a for loop to dynamically create a set of form variables per each service ID and action combo. I need some help to know what direction to go. I am confused on how to get this started.

Comment: VB.NET is an object-oriented language and you should be using that fact.  Define a type that includes properties for all the relevant data, e.g. a `ServiceId`, an `Action`, a `FirstName`, etc.  For the actions, I suggest that you define an `Enum` and then make the corresponding property that type.  You can then store a list of your type in a session variable.

Answer (score 1):

In a situation like this, I would consider a multi dimensional array, and if the services are not changing, consider storing it in an application array Application on Start

```
  Dim aryServices(3, 4) As Object '4 services, 3 properties per service
  aryServices.SetValue(1, 0, 0)
  aryServices.SetValue("Action A", 1, 0)
  aryServices.SetValue("First Name, Last Name, Address", 2, 0)
  aryServices.SetValue(2, 0, 1)
  aryServices.SetValue("Action B", 1, 1)
  aryServices.SetValue("First Name, Last Name,ZipCode", 2, 1)
  aryServices.SetValue(3, 0, 2)
  aryServices.SetValue("Action C", 1, 2)
  aryServices.SetValue("First Name, Last Name,Password", 2, 2)
  aryServices.SetValue(4, 0, 3)
  aryServices.SetValue("Action D", 1, 3)
  aryServices.SetValue("Last Name,Password", 2, 3)
  Application.Item("aryServices") = aryServices
```

If you had a service id of zero, that would be great because then you could just match up the service ID with the array index.  When you need to look something up, you can grab the array like this:

```
Dim aryServices(,) As Object = Application.Item("aryServices")
Response.Write(aryServices.GetValue(1, 1))
```

It's not as efficient as a dictionary object, but sometimes at the start of a project this method has been a simple way for me to get started.